# wpf get screen position of selected item in listview

Tags: wpf

In the mouseup event for a listview, how do I get the screen position of a selected item?  I can get the screen position of the listview itself (.pointtoscreen) but can't find a way to determine the screen position of a selected item.

I've reviewed other SO articles but didn't find anything specific to items in the listview.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough for you to get the position of the mouse on the screen when it is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the `ListBox.SelectionChanged` event (or `Selector.Selected`). Then get the container of the selected item to calculate its coordinates:

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var selectedItemContainer = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as UIElement;
    var pointOnSelectedItem = new Point(); // top-left corner

    var pointOnScreen = selectedItemContainer.PointToScreen(pointOnSelectedItem);
    var pointRelativeToWindow = selectedItemContainer.TranslatePoint(pointOnSelectedItem, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is crazy. The only available and complete answer. You are the best.